# Issues trying to do 'npm install create-react-app' - why am i getting a saveError with a package.lock.json?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, installation, npm-install, package.json

I'm trying to build a website using react.js, I have built a few with no issues now I'm seeing this error regardless of making dedicated project folders.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled in the global and local folders, none of it seems to work properly

[[image: Screenshot]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `create-react-app` globally you need to use the `-g` option:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Otherwise it will be installed locally inside the current working directory.

If you are using an npm version > 5.1 you can also use the command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

which will install `create-react-app` automatically if not already installed.

Comment: I've done -g(global) and local, they both generate the same error.. I've done the 'npm uninstall create-react-app' and installed it again.